# Argparse: str object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Not sure what is going on here. Passing 2 arguments to an argparser, getting an error. Am I passing my arguments improperly?

Here is the code I am running.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-dspath', '--datasheet-path', required=True, dest='datasheet_path', type=str, help='path to data')
parser.add_argument('-pname', '--project-name', required=True, dest='project_name', type=str, help='name of project')
args = parser.parse_args("./path_to_project", "name_of_project")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ayoung/PycharmProjects/pdf_scraper_atul/datasheet_rms_comparator 3.py", line 1320, in <module>
    args = parse_args()
  File "/Users/ayoung/PycharmProjects/pdf_scraper_atul/datasheet_rms_comparator 3.py", line 26, in parse_args
    args = parser.parse_args("./path_to_project", "name_of_project")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1749, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1772, in parse_known_args
    setattr(namespace, action.dest, action.default)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datasheet_path'
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes, parse_args takes a sequence, not positional arguments, so `parse_args(('a', 'b'))` or `parse_args(['a', 'b'])` and not `parse_args('a', 'b')`

Comment: Thanks, but just getting an error: "the following arguments are required: -dspath/--datasheet-path, -pname/--project-name", so the arguments aren't being recognized.

Comment: @AndrewYoung You shouldn't pass any args to `parse_args`.

Comment: the things you pass into `parse_args` *are* the command line arguments, if you want to parse from the commandline (`sys.argv[1:]`) you'll call `parse_args()` with no arguments

Comment: Thanks guys, I kind of see now. But how would I send the project path and name without sending them to parse_args()? Where do I send them?

Comment: You have defined your parser to take arguments indicated by the names ``-dspath``/``--datasheet-path`` and ``-pname``/``--project-name``, yet *don't* pass these names.

Comment: @AndrewYoung If you already have the path and name, why send them to arparse in the first place?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Correct. I am trying to understand how to send these arguments, apparently they don't get sent in parse_args().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `argparse` is not taking any positional arguments, you have to include the `--flags` to tell `argparse` where to look for the arguments.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-dspath', '--datasheet-path', required=True, dest='datasheet_path', type=str, help='path to data')
parser.add_argument('-pname', '--project-name', required=True, dest='project_name', type=str, help='name of project')
args = parser.parse_args(["--datasheet-path", "./path_to_project", "--project-name", "name_of_project"])

print(args)
```

Running this script gives us...

```sh
$ python parseArgs.py
Namespace(datasheet_path='./path_to_project', project_name='name_of_project')
```

Comment: ``argparse`` has no problem taking positional arguments. However, they have to be added as such.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, that's why I said "`argparse` is not taking any positional arguments," not `argparse` cannot take positional arguments ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're passing them improperly. They should be in a sequence, like a list:

```
args = parser.parse_args(["./path_to_project", "name_of_project"])
```

*Thanks to [Anthony Sottile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812183/anthony-sottile) for pointing this out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084062/argparse-str-object-has-no-attribute#comment108066142_61084062)*

The reason for that error is `parse_args` is expecting its second argument to be a **namespace**. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args):

> ```
> ArgumentParser.parse_args(args=None, namespace=None)
> ```
>
> Convert argument strings to objects and assign them as attributes of the namespace.

---

However, then you get another error:

```
usage: test.py [-h] -dspath DATASHEET_PATH -pname PROJECT_NAME
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: -dspath/--datasheet-path, -pname/--project-name
```

Which you can fix by passing the required options:

```
args = parser.parse_args(["-dspath", "./path_to_project", "-pname", "name_of_project"])
```

Or by turning your options into positional arguments:

```
parser.add_argument('datasheet_path', help='path to data')
parser.add_argument('project_name', help='name of project')
args = parser.parse_args(["./path_to_project", "name_of_project"])
print(args)
# Namespace(datasheet_path='./path_to_project', project_name='name_of_project')
```

BTW `type=str` is implied and I switched the argument names to have underscores instead of dashes.

Answer (score 0):

First point: [the second argument to `parser.parse_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) is :

> An object to take the attributes. The default is a new empty Namespace object.

Which explains your first error (strings are immutable, you can't set attributes on them).

Second point: [by prefixing your arguments names with "-"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags), you make them named arguments, so you have to pass them as such, not as positional arguments.

Answer (score -4):

replace `datasheet_path` with `datasheet-path`